# Does "Verb to be" imply something?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, descriptive-grammar

> This is.... blah blah. They shocked and angered, when the people sought to deprive them.

compare to this

> This is.... blah blah. They **are** shocked and angered, when the people sought to deprive them.

does this imply something ?

Comment: The English verbs _shock_ and _anger_ are **causative** verbs. They refer to somebody (the subject) causing somebody else to feel shock or anger. The participles _shocked_ and _angered_ can be used as predicate adjectives (with the meaningless auxiliary _be_, like all predicate adjectives or nouns) to express the state, or as passives to express having the experience; but they can't be used in the active with inchoative meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"*They shocked and angered*" is grammatically incorrect in the context used here. It must have some verb (are, were) like your second version.

It does work in this usage "*They shocked and angered [somebody], when people...*"

By the way, the tense of the verbs should match, either

> They **are** shocked and angered, when the people **seek** to deprive them.

or

> They **were** shocked and angered, when the people **sought** to deprive them.

Comment: Please do not try to use `<br>` to create blank lines, because that is not what it does. Here we're WYSIWYG, so If you want a blank line, just use a blank line.

Comment: @tchrist oops, I knew that! been editing too much HTML recently over on Squarespace.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> The English verbs *shock* and *anger* are **causative** verbs. They refer to somebody (the subject) causing somebody else to feel shock or anger. The participles *shocked* and *angered* can be used as predicate adjectives (with the meaningless auxiliary *be*, like all predicate adjectives or nouns) to express the state, or as passives to express having the experience; but they can't be used in the active with inchoative meaning.